# Change shapefile coordinate system using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, pyproj, kartograph

I am struggling with Python and Kartograph.py. I'd like to change coordinate system of the whole shapefile from EPSG:5514 to EPSG:4326. Found some code in here working for points, but I don't know how to cope with shapefile. Code for point goes like this:

```py
from kartograph import Kartograph
from pyproj import Proj, transform

K = Kartograph()
# S-JTSK EPSG:5514
# Kartograph uses EPSG:4326

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:5514', preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

x1,y1 = -599411.949672, -599411.949672
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
```

Do I need to do anything like this for shp?

```py
from kartograph import Kartograph
from pyproj import Proj, transform

K = Kartograph()
# S-JTSK EPSG:5514
# Kartograph uses EPSG:4326

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:5514', preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

for point in shapefile:
    SX = #coordinateX in shp attribute table
    SY = #coordinateY
    x1,y1 = -599411.949672, -599411.949672 #do something to transform every point
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's some handy code from the [Python GDAL/OGR cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#reproject-a-layer) that will reproject a shapefile.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import os

in_epsg = 5514
out_epsg = 4326
in_shp = '/path/to/input.shp'
out_shp = '/path/to/reprojected.shp'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

# input SpatialReference
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(in_epsg)

# output SpatialReference
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(out_epsg)

# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# get the input layer
inDataSet = driver.Open(in_shp)
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()

# create the output layer
if os.path.exists(out_shp):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(out_shp)
outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(out_shp)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("reproject", geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)

# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

# loop through the input features
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    # reproject the geometry
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the shapefile
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # dereference the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature = None
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# Save and close the shapefiles
inDataSet = None
outDataSet = None
```

Comment: This doesn't work in gdal version 3.0.2. I just found that out the hard way. It does seem to work in gdal version 2.3.3.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I just made a tiny modification: `outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("reproject", geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)`  for `outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer(
    "reproject", outSpatialRef, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)`. It was to specify the CRS in output file.

Answer (score 6):

Here is even more concise option using **geopandas** library:

```
import geopandas

data = geopandas.read_file(path+file_in)
# change CRS to epsg 4326
data = data.to_crs(epsg=4326)
# write shp file
data.to_file(path+file_out)
```

BTW Kartograph is not developed anymore according to developer git-hub page!

Comment: I like this code except that the proj4 string I have for 28992 is not working as I expect. The generated shapefile in arcgis properties shows that it is stereographic projection. However, it doesn't confirm to all standards of 28992 :( Any suggestions?https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/amersfoort-rd-new/proj4/

Comment: you project the data in wgs84, but then you use a proj string to define the projection as a UTM projection. Therefor your coordinate value are coorect, but the crs is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

By using **fiona** and **shapely** the code is more concise:

```
from kartograph import Kartograph
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Point

from fiona.crs import from_epsg
crs = from_epsg(4326)

K = Kartograph()
# S-JTSK EPSG:5514
# Kartograph uses EPSG:4326
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:32612', preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.shp'

points = fiona.open(path)

new_points = []

for point in points:
    x, y = point['geometry']['coordinates']
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x, y)
    new_points.append((x2, y2))

# creation of the resulting shapefile
schema1 = {'geometry': 'Point','properties': {'id': 'int'},}
with fiona.open('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/reprojected_points.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema1, crs)  as output:

    for i, point in enumerate(new_points):
        output.write({'geometry':mapping(Point(point[0], point[1])),'properties': {'id':i}})
```

I tried it out with point shapefile indicated at code as **random_points.shp** (EPSG:32612). After running it at Python Console, I loaded reprojected shapefile at Map View of QGIS and it was transformed adequately (as it can be observed at following image).

[image]

Now, it is available to use with **kartograph** python module.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem with the code in this link; https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#reproject-a-layer.

Researching I found the solution here; https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546#issuecomment-616344351

then the solution is to add the following line;

inSpatialRef.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.