# How do you create a "donut hole" / cut-out-effect using folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, shapely, folium

I've tried adjusting parameters and changing the order in which these circles are added. I can't get the interior circle, or "hole", to remain transparent. The outer circle always predominates.

```
m = folium.Map(tiles="cartodbpositron", location=xy, zoom_start=14, attr="CartoDB")

folium.Circle(xy, radius=1800, fill=True, fill_opacity=.5, fill_color='black').add_to(m)
folium.Circle(xy, radius=1000, fill=False, fill_opacity=0, fill_color=None).add_to(m)

m
```

In effect, I'm trying to do what Shapely does:

`donut = Point(0, 0).buffer(2.0).difference(Point(0, 0).buffer(1.0))`

But I want to do it with Folium because projecting a circle made with Shapely yields an object that's rough, even elliptical.

[image: Folium Donut Hole attempt]

Answer (score 1):

You can unfortunately not do this that way, with two circles on top of each other.
A Circle element with a hole in it should be drawn as a polygon with a hole in it.

You should use what you did:

> donut = Point(0, 0).buffer(2.0).difference(Point(0, 0).buffer(1.0))

In order to have it shown not as an elliptical geometry, you should take care of using **projected coordinates** instead of geographical coordinates.
This can be done with (for example) [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting). See [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287354/162).

Comment: I tried `donut.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}` and it still projects an ellipse. If I do `geopandas.GeoSeries(donut).to_crs(epsg=4326)`, I get `ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.` Can you elaborate, please?