# Projecting GeoJSON

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geojson

I have a shapefile in EPSG 4326 and am trying to project it to 3857. I am using the GDAL [cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html) example, but changing what I need. I continue to get a `NoneType object has no attribute 'GetLayer'` error. I used [numerous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265589/change-shapefile-coordinate-system-using-python) scripts from other solutions regarding projecting a `.shp`. Though I continue to fall into this error.

Any suggestions?

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import os

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

# input SpatialReference
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# output SpatialReference
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3857)

# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# get the input layer
inDataSet = driver.Open('D:/Scripts/Stand19North.geojson')
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()

# create the output layer
outputShapefile = 'D:/Scripts/Reproject3857.shp'
if os.path.exists(outputShapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outputShapefile)
outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("Reproject3857.shp", geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)

# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

# loop through the input features
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    # reproject the geometry
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the shapefile
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # dereference the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature = None
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# Save and close the shapefiles
inDataSet = None
outDataSet = None
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Scripts/shp_projection.py", line 8, in <module>
    inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer']
```

Edits:
Converted my .geojson to a .shp, though I continue to get the same error.

Comment: You can't open a GeoJSON file with the Shapefile driver

Comment: So I would need to convert to .shp first? or is there a driver for geojson?

Comment: Okay, so I converted to a .shp and still get the same error

Comment: My bad, I inputed the incorrect file. This works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/projections.html) does this without the need to use OGR.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('file.json')
gdf.to_crs('EPSG:3857')
```